# Tool for creating animated timeline Infographic?

Tags: animation, information-graphics

I'm looking for a tool to create an Infographic-like timeline (historical, like in the picture below), but I need it also to be animated by auto-scrolling from beginning to end of timeline either horizontally or vertically. The tool should be able to extract the project as movie or gif.

[image]

**visme**

I checked https://www.visme.co/ and I saw the option to download the project as MP4, but I wasn't sure if this is what I need because I need to pay to enable it. I'm OK with paying but after I know for fact it will help me accomplish the timeline as required. Would appreciate if someone can confirm.

[image]

Comment: I think you might get better answers in other Stack Exchange sites, like maybe Super User... Or other platforms entirely. I would do this using After Effects and it seems like you're looking for something much more simpler. I personally don't have any experience with apps like that. I would also consider Adobe Animate and Tumult Hype. If it's going to end up on a website and I didn't need it to be a video, all of these support some kind of canvas or svg animation export, which _can_ also be interactive. But I'm pretty sure you're not ready for the learning curve of any of those apps.

Comment: If I were you, I'd probably email Visme.co's support and ask if it works the way you think it works. But yes, mp4 is a video format and if you need a video format, that would be it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to find the correct stack exchange site, and wrote in this one as I found similar questions about timelines design.

Comment: @Joonas: I think Super User will close questions about software recommendation. but I am not sure.

Comment: @C.F.G, yea... I don't have much experience.... I thought was pretty much 50% software recommendations and 50% software issues.

Comment: @Cortex, yea it's not a big deal if it doesn't fit here. I don't know if the question is or isn't a good fit here, I was mostly just thinking that most graphic designers here wouldn't know too much about applications such as `visme.co`, where the target market seems to be like your average marketing and/or sales guy or your regular office worker perhaps... and not so much graphic designers. Although not all graphic designers do animation either.

Comment: Adobe AfterEffects probably. But this would be a video editing question. Perhaps ask on Video Production Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 3 step workflow here

> A tool to create an Infographic-like timeline (historical, like in the picture below)

1. Chose any design application. I would use a vector-based one like Illustrator, Corel Draw, Affinity Design or **Inkscape**. Make the first group of objects, duplicate and change the inside elements.

Make your infographic but for now, it will be static.

I would export all the infographics to a single raster image. A Png.

> I need it also to be animated by auto-scrolling from beginning to end of timeline either horizontally or vertically.

You do not need auto-scrolling. That sounds to me like a webpage, but as you need a video file I will forget about "scrolling" at all.

You need to animate the timeline so either each data or a group of them show, probably stop to be read, and move again to reveal new dates.

The simplest animation tool is probably PowerPoint. Put your image, adjust the size and position. Duplicate the slide and adjust the new position.

You can also use **Blender**, or **HitFilm** which are free but have a learning curve.

> The tool should be able to extract the project like a movie or gif.

3. If you can, use a movie, not Gif. All Blender, HitFilm and PowerPoint can export to a video file.

---

If you still want to use that website... Ask them. It has a help chat at the bottom.

[image]